# id class not generated in R.java using eclipse

Tags: android, adt

I installed the eclipse and ADT plug. When I am going to create new project the id class is not creating in R.java. I want to create button and textfields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add views to your Layout file main.xml....it will get automatically created....

Comment: how to Add views to Layout file main.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do following things...
1. Just clean your project... It will regenerate R.java file.
2. If still there is an error then surely u have error in layout file.

Comment: I have cleaned my project and Project is set to Build Automatically and i delete the R.java file and regenerate it automatically but problem is not resolving.

Comment: dear Rashmi problem has been resolved after set layout file code. thanks for your right instruction.

Comment: Ok thanks!!! Dont forget to mark the answer as right if you satisfied with the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Project is set to Build Automatically.
If it is not getting generated, check the Problems description in the Eclipse window to see why the build is failing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a strange answer, but the fact of remove all files 'Thumbs.db' from all subfolders of resources has fixed the problem (on WIndows).